# Vercel and AWS RDS, VPN site-to-site

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, vercel

My application is running on Vercel and require connection to AWS RDS, but now it publicly accessible. Suggest, please, any approaches I can use to secure the connection. I want to setup site-to-site vpn connection, but not sure if Vercel provide this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

I work with Vercel the second week and can't see any documentation related my problem